# Ruby doesn't recognize `downcase` or `split` as defined methods?

Tags: ruby

The issue is with the following code:

```
#write your code here
def translate phrase
  phrase = phrase.downcase.split(/ /)
  phrase.collect! do |word|
    word = word.split(//)
    switched = false
    while switched == false
      word.each_index do |letter| 
        if word[letter] == ("a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u")
          switched = true
          word = (word[letter..-1] + word[0..(letter-1)]).join + "ay"
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return phrase.join(" ")
end

puts translate("chocolate cream")
#Should return "ocolatechay eamcray"
```

When I run this, Ruby just returns a blank line. So, to troubleshoot the issue, I loaded the definition into a repl. The repl returned the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `downcase' for #<RubyVM::InstructionSequence:0x000000016e8f88>
    from /home/adc/odin-project/web-development-101/21-ruby-tdd/ruby_tdd_project/learn_ruby/04_pig_latin/pig_latin.rb:3:in `translate'
    from /home/adc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

If I remove `downcase` from my code, I get the same error message, only this time with `split`.

What's the problem here? (I'm pretty confident that `downcase` and `split` are *not* the problem.)

Comment: Where is `phrase` coming from? As you can see in the error message, it's not a String but a [RubyVM::InstructionSequence](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/RubyVM/InstructionSequence.html)

Comment: `phrase` is just an argument for the `translate` method. I've tried defining `phrase` as a string within the repl, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If returns a blank string because you don't return anything inside the `collect!` block. Return `word` and it will work :

```
def translate phrase
  phrase = phrase.downcase.split(/ /)
  phrase.collect! do |word|
    word = word.split(//)
    switched = false
    while switched == false
      word.each_index do |letter|
        if word[letter] == ("a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u")
          switched = true
          word = (word[letter..-1] + word[0..(letter-1)]).join + "ay"
        end
      end
    end
    word
  end
  return phrase.join(" ")
end

puts translate("chocolate cream")
#=> atechocolay amcreay
```

It doesn't look like it's returning exactly what you expected, but it's still better than a blank string.

As for your weird error message in the console, it seems to be specific to the REPL (possibly because of the method name `translate`).

Comment: Yep, it does seem like using `translate` or `phrase` is throwing the error (if I change either term, the error goes). Thanks—this answers the question, even though the code isn't yet working as intended.

Comment: @adc The problem that you assigned word inside word loop. Give me your expected answer in this example `puts translate("methods unavailable")` please.

Comment: @arm2pro "ethodsmay unavailableay"

Comment: @adc look solution in the bellow!

Comment: @arm2pro, thanks, but can you explain why mine doesn't work? I don't understand why assigning word within the word loop is a problem—it looks like you've done the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 1** (how I would write this code)

```
def translate phrase
  phrase = phrase.downcase.split(/ /)
  phrase.collect! do |word|
    word = word.split(//)

    word.each_index do |letter| 
      if ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].include?(word[letter])
        if letter == 0
          word = word[letter..-1].join + "ay"
        else
          word = (word[letter..-1] + word[0..(letter-1)]).join + "ay"
        end

        break
      end
    end

    word
  end

  return phrase.join(" ")
end

puts translate("chocolate cream")
```

**Update 2** (if I make some minor changes to your code to make it useful)

```
def translate phrase
  phrase = phrase.downcase.split(/ /)
  phrase.collect! do |word|
    word = word.split(//)
    switched = false
    while switched == false
      word.each_index do |letter| 
        if ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].include?(word[letter])
          switched = true
          if letter == 0
            word = word[letter..-1].join + "ay"
          else
            word = (word[letter..-1] + word[0..(letter-1)]).join + "ay"
          end
          break
        end
      end
    end
    word
  end
  return phrase.join(" ")
end

puts translate("chocolate cream")
```

**Explanation**

1. `"o"==("a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u")`

   and

   `"o"== "a" || "o" == "e" || "o" == "i" || "o" == "o" || "o" == "u"`

   statements are not the same. First one is false

   (because  `("a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u")=="a"` and `"o"!="a"`), since the second one is true.
2. You need inner if statement

   ```
   if letter == 0
     word = word[letter..-1].join + "ay"
   else
     word = (word[letter..-1] + word[0..(letter-1)]).join + "ay"
   end
   ```

   because when word starts with any mentioned vowels then

   `word[letter..-1] + word[0..(letter-1)]`

   statement will return the whole word twice, cause letter will equal to 0.
3. And lastly you need to return `word` object after the while loop.

Comment: ok, so I see two main changes. `word` is now `letters` until == the final word to be returned, and you're using `break` instead of my `switched` idea. If you can explain why those two changes are necessary, I'd be grateful.

Comment: @adc please see my update.

Comment: Thanks @arm2pro, but I'm still not sure why my `switched` idea doesn't work? Your **Update 2** only works because `break` is there as well.

Comment: @adc You may missed the `word` object return part after while loop. I added point 3 as well.

Comment: @adc look without break your loop `word.each_index do |letter| ` will continue even if it met first occur in the word. In the end you will get wrong result, that is for break is there to interrupt that loop and give it to while loop which will ends as well because `switched=true` already.